# Selecting and renaming columns in SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sp

I'm working with a feature class dataset extracted from a geodatabase, which I've filtered to my area of interest and intersected with a SpatialPointsDataFrame. In order to export it to a shapefile with WriteOGR I need to format the attribute names and I also want to only select specific columns to export in my final shapefile. I have been running into a lot of errors using standard select or base R subletting techniques. For some reason R doesn't seem to recognize the column  names when I try to select. I've tried lots of different methods and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

````
```bfcln%>%
+ select(STATEFP,DP2_HC03_V, DP2_HC03V.1)

Error in tolower(use) : object 'STATEFP' not found```


# create a spatial join between bf_pop and or_acs 
#check CRS
```crsbf <- bf_pop@proj4string```

# change acs CRS to match bf_pop 
```oracs_reprj <- spTransform(or_acs, crsbf)```

# join by spatial attributes 
```bf_int <- raster::intersect(bf_pop, oracs_reprj)```

#truncate field names to 10 characters for ESRI formatting
```names(bf_int) <- strtrim(names(bf_int),10)```
#remove duplicates from attribute table
```bfcln <- bf_int[which(!duplicated(bf_int$id)), ]```
````

After failing with the select() method multiple times, I tried renaming columns.

````
# rename variables of interest 
```bfcln1 <-bfcln%>%
      select(DP2_HC03_V)%>%
      rename(DP2_HC03_V=pcntunmar)%>%
      select(DP2_HC03_V.1)%>%
      rename(DP2_HC03_V.1=pcntirsh)

Error in tolower(use) : object 'DP2_HC03_V' not found```
````

Comment: It is probably easier to convert your `sp` object to `sf` object and then use `dplyr::select`.

Comment: Since you did not share a reproducible example, there is nothing I can do.

Comment: In order to access data frame, you can use `bfcln@data`.

Answer (score 0):

To rename spatial files you'll need to install the package **spdplyr**.

Similarly to dplyr, you'd do:

```
df <- df %>%
```

rename(newName = oldName)